# Date format requirement like this 2023/01/24 15:21:54.967981100

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I checked it `2023/01/24 15:21:54.967981100` this format is not supported in SQL Server.

Do we have any other way to get format like this?
I tried with below date format

```
CONCAT(
          CONVERT(varchar(23), modon, 111),
          ' ',
          SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(23), modon, 121), 11, 13))
```

and getting data like this 2023/01/24  15:21:54.000

Comment: 1) Formatting dates is a client app job, not a database job, so why are you doing it here? 2) Did you try the `FORMAT` function?

Comment: Also I note you haven't accepted an answer to any of your questions? Is that intentional? It is *usual* to accept an answer.

Comment: You could extract the datetime part supported by SQL server as a separate column, and have your longer formatted timestamp saved as an nvarchar if you want to keep it this format and get some value out of it as well.

Comment: Try `FORMAT(SYSUTCDATETIME(), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff00')`. SQL Server supports a maximum of 7 fractional digits, so the last two digits are added in the format as literal zeros.

Comment: Where did you "check"? I can see a format that is *incredibly* similar, and (presumably) you know how to `REPLACE` a character.

Answer (score 1):

There are [lots of styles available](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) for `CONVERT`; unfortunately, none produce the exact format you want.

But style `14`, for example, lets you isolate time, so no messy `SUBSTRING` stuff. We can also use `char(len+1)` to take advantage of its trailing space. Assuming the source is `datetime2`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  CONVERT(char(11), modon, 111),
  CONVERT(char(16), modon, 14),
  '00')
FROM ...;
```

If it's `datetime`, you'll have to add a few more zeroes and use `char(12)`, because you only get three decimal places there:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  CONVERT(char(11), modon, 111),
  CONVERT(char(12), modon, 14),
  '000000')
FROM ...;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/697jozpo)

Also, to Thom's point, you could do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  REPLACE(CONVERT(char(23), getdate(), 121),'-','/'),
  '000000');

SELECT CONCAT(
  REPLACE(CONVERT(char(27), sysdatetime(), 121),'-','/'),
  '00');
```

- [Updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Ylnld-s)

Style numbers are cryptic and hard to memorize (why I wrote [that post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), I use it myself all the time). But I wouldn't use `FORMAT`, because it is notoriously slow at scale (which I also wrote about, [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but), [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7144/sql-date-format-comparison-sql-format-sql-convert/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7145/sql-date-format-comparison-computed-column-materialized-column/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports in its datetime data types is 3 milliseconds for `datetime` and 100 nanoseconds for `datetime2`

```
DECLARE @YourDate datetime2 = GETDATE();
SELECT 
    FORMAT(@YourDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff') as FormattedDate;
```